# validation depends on radio button selection laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have different inputs depends on radio buttons. How to validate them according to selection?

```php
<div class="sm:col-span-2">
    <div class="mt-4">
        <nav class=" " aria-label="Tabs">
            <div class="border-gray-300 border-2 rounded-lg pl-3 py-2 w-40" :class="tab == 'tab1' ? ' bg-green-200 border-green-500 ' : ''">
            <input type="radio" @click="tab = 'tab1'"  checked="tab == 'tab1' ? true: false" name="person_company"> <span class="text-gray-600  font-medium text-sm pl-2">person</span> </input> 
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="border-gray-300 border-2 rounded-lg pl-3 py-2 w-40" :class="tab == 'tab2' ? ' bg-green-200 border-green-500 ' : '  '">
            <input type="radio" @click="tab = 'tab2'"   name="person_company"> <span class="text-gray-600  font-medium text-sm pl-2">company</span> </input>
            </div>                                    
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sm:col-span-2 " x-show="tab == 'tab1'">
    <label for="identity_no" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Identity</label>
    <div class="mt-1">
        <input type="text" name="identity_no" id="identity_no" class="block w-full py-4 border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 sm:text-sm">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sm:col-span-2" x-show="tab == 'tab2'">
    <label for="company" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Company name</label>
    <div class="mt-1">
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="block w-full py-4 border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 sm:text-sm">
    </div>
</div>
```

this code needs both of them that's not what I want

```php
$this->validate($request,[
            'identity' => 'required', 
            'company' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery to manage it. First of all, you will have to take values to radio inputs. And then apply the required property through jquery condition.

```
<input type="radio" @click="tab = 'tab1'"  checked="tab == 'tab1' ? true: false" name="person_company" value = "tab1"> <span class="text-gray-600  font-medium text-sm pl-2">person</span> </input>

<input type="radio" @click="tab = 'tab2'"   name="person_company"> <span class="text-gray-600  font-medium text-sm pl-2" value = "tab2">company</span> </input>

$('input[type=radio][name= person_company]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'tab1') {
        $("#identity_no").prop('required',true);
        $("#company").prop('required',false);
    }
    else if (this.value == 'tab2') {
        $("#company").prop('required',true);
        $("#identity_no").prop('required',false);
    }
});
```